# Is abbreviating the object clause in this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I want to say "The first time I heard about something was ***when I was*** around 8 years' old".
Is "***when I was***" here redundant and unnecessary?
Is that a part of object clause?
Are "First time I heard about xyz from friends was around 8." and "***8 years' old***" correct?

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you for answering. I think "The first time I heard about something" is subject, and have verb "was", so I assume the sentence "when I was around 8 years' old" must be object, hence "object clause", isn't it? And, is "8 years old" correct but "8 <i><strong>years'</strong></i> old" not?

Comment: Your are right that "The first time I heard about something" is subject, but the verb is not transitive ("be" is intransitive) so there is no object. What follows "be" is obligatory, and obligatory items are always complements, and hence "when I was around 8 years' old" is a complement.

Comment: @Otryaddarkh: The verb is *was* and it will not take an object. Whereas, It has the *complement* (when I was around 8 years old.) You can reduce the complement -clause as: ***The first time I heard about it was at the age of eight.*** BTW *8 years old*, not *8 years' old*.

Comment: A further point about the complement: some people analyse "when" as a subordinator and thus the complement as a subordinate clause. Others follow some modern grammars and take "when" as a preposition, and the complement thus a PP. The latter analysis (which I prefer) can be paraphrased as "at the time when I was around 8 years old".